# How to store selected avatar into database

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, bootstrap-4

I want to show only 10 avatars on website from which user can choose his avatar.
There will be no uploading kind of thing.
The user will choose by clicking on avatar img and then click the button "done". The choosen avatar name should be go into the database and his profile icon will get change to selected avatar.

I searched a lot for this. But I was unable to find

Looking forward to give me some idea about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you done so far. you know we are here to help but not to do everything from scratch

Comment: I know . I have created modal having those 10 avatar images. But i dont have idea about how to implement it. Some idea will be helpful @ahmednawazbutt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this

Create a table for `avatars`

- id
- name
- path_to_image

Show this list while selecting the avatar on UI. Reference this table's `ID` in user's table/class

Comment: I have to select that image by just clicking on image itself and then click the submit button. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you share your HTML/JS part. Or you are looking for an exact code for your question?

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to make a database table with - the easiest one - a base64 encoded image. In this case it will be your avatar. After that every avatar has an id.

Then in the user table you can make a new column, for example userAvatarId and this id references to the avatar database table. Then you can easily change the id's and therefore the avatars.

Comment: I got this but how will I  select the image from the website and send that particular id to database

Comment: You can get every id pointed to the base64 encoded image. Then you can store metadata information for these images. For example you have a row, made with a simple for loop, and then you can select the id easily with that.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Sorry, I am beginner in this field, can you pls share some kind of code in any php or angular lang